# Presenting an icon in place of text

Tags: page-layout

I'd like to display an icon, rather than text of a URL, when an administrator fills in a field. 
Specifically, if they enter a Facebook URL, I want the Facebook icon to appear on the page, hyperlinked to the URL, without displaying the URL.  If there's no entry in the field, then no icon appears.

Comment: where you want ot do this ? what you have tried ? can you provide some information?

Comment: Essentially, I've added a Site Column called 'Facebook Location', where a user can enter their facebook address if one exists. (We have many offices, some with Facebook accounts, some without).  If they've entered an address, I want the facebook icon to appear. If it's blank, I don't want the icon to appear.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using JSLink. It is used to change the look of a list view, it needs javascript expertise to write a code that will render the field to show an icon instead of a URL. There are many posts out there that teaches how to integrate JSLink in your list and can find very good examples that can be tweaked to serve you in [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a)